# What is the relative memory overhead per mapped value of the different Java map types

Tags: java, performance, memory

I have a case where I have "property maps" one each attached to a very large collection of objects. I am only interested in the overhead of the map itself not of the attached keys and values.

Many have a small number of properties ie: < 5, and many none.  For empty maps I use a singleton "empty instance" as an optimization.

For speed it seems that at a count of <= 5, TreeMap seems equal or better than HashMap for retrieval and "auto trims" when nodes are removed.  I would think a HashMap uses for each entry the memory overhead of the hash/handle array including memory above the load factor full of null entry handles, and the object overhead and handle storage for the key and the value in the "Entry[+internal fields if any]".

Also I would think a TreeMap uses only the per Entry Object overhead + key,value,prev,next handle fields in the entry for the list, and the smallest possible a binary search of an array - One array object (trimmed to size) full of just the handles for the keys and the values.

Has anyone really checked the accurate full overhead of each of the Java map types?  For my bazillions of objects with properties it would make a significant difference in the 1 to 5 property case without impacting speed of access.

Comment: You can use java memory profiler (e.g., visualvm or yourkit) to examine byte cost of java objects.

Comment: I would try playing with the initial size of the HashMap. Iterating through a very small number of keys is not that expensive.  Try something like `new HashMap<>(4, 2f)` or even `new HashMap<>(2, 3f)`  Note the capacity is always a power of 2.

Comment: And two links: www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/.../memory-efficient-java-tutorial.pdf and http://www.slideshare.net/DawidWeiss/sizeofobject-how-much-memory-objects-take-on-jvms-and-when-this-may-matter

Comment: @VictorSorokin good links to determininig VM implemetation memory use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

https://code.google.com/p/memory-measurer/wiki/ElementCostInDataStructures

`TreeMap` and `HashMap` use approximately the same amount of memory per entry, though it's true that `TreeMap` has a slightly smaller constant overhead for the map itself.

Answer (score 2):

If your property maps are not updated actively, but built once and queried for more or less long time, I would propose a Java-specific memory saving architecture:

```
public interface DynamicMap<K, V> {
    DynamicMap<K, V> add(K key, V value);
    V get(K key);
}

class WrappingDynamicMap<K, V> implements DynamicMap<K, V> {
    DynamicMap<K, V> delegate;
    public void put(K key, V value) { delegate = add(key, value); }

    @Override public DynamicMap<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
        if (delegate == null) return new Map1<>(key, value);
        return delegate.add(key, value);
    }

    @Override public V get(K key) { return delegate.get(key); }
}

class Map1<K, V> implements DynamicMap<K, V> {
    K k1; V v1;
    Map1(K k1, V v1) { this.k1 = k1; this.v1 = v1; }

    boolean putThis(K key, V value) {
        if (key.equals(k1)) { v1 = value; return true; }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public DynamicMap<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
        if (putThis(key, value)) return this;
        return new Map2<>(this, key, value);
    }

    @Override public V get(K key) { return key.equals(k1) ? v1 : null; }
}

class Map2<K, V> extends Map1<K, V> {
    K k2; V v2;
    Map2(Map1<K, V> m, K k2, V v2) {
        super(m.k1, m.v1); this.k2 = k2; this.v2 = v2;
    }

    @Override boolean putThis(K key, V value) {
        if (super.putThis(key, value)) return true;
        if (key.equals(k2)) { v2 = value; return true; }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public DynamicMap<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
        if (putThis(key, value)) return this;
        HashMap<K,V>hm=new HashMap<K,V>(){{
            put(k1,v1);put(k2,v2);put(key,value);}};
        return new BigMap<>(hm);
    }

    @Override public V get(K key) {
        V v = super.get(key);
        return v != null ? v : (key.equals(k2) ? v2 : null);
    }
}

// Map3, Map4, Map5

class BigMap<K, V> implements DynamicMap<K, V> {
    private HashMap<K, V> impl;
    BigMap(HashMap<K, V> impl) { this.impl = impl; }

    @Override public DynamicMap<K, V> add(K key, V value) {
        impl.put(key, value); return this;
    }

    @Override public V get(K key) { return impl.get(key); }
}
```

If you need classic Map interface, use `WrappingDynamicMap` with `put()`, if you can afford to reassign property map field within the object on each map put, you can use `DynamicMap` implementations directly with `add()`, it would safe 1 dereference on each query and 16-24 bytes on heap for each property map.

Advantages of this approach:

- I bet this would be much faster than `HashMap`/`TreeMap` on sizes 1..3-5 depending on your key's `equals()` complexity
- Use absolute minimum memory to hold the data
- Could be easily specialized for primitive keys/values

Disadvantages:

- GC pressure on map puts/removes

I hope it's clear how removes could be implemented for `Map1`/`Map2`/../`BigMap`. `BigMap` could also monitor `impl.size()` and turn back to `Map5` eventually.

Additional opportunities:

- For size between 5 and 12 very-very simple open-addressing hash table implementation (with constant modulo 16) could be used instead of `HashMap`, with size stored as `byte`.

Comment: Yes in my case the object with the properties attached to it is the "DynamicMap" with getProperty() setProperty() and removeProperty() as public final calls, and the management of what those delegate to is done internally.

Comment: I might add here that no primitive field in a java object on a 32 bit processor uses less than 32 bits no matter what size it is.

Comment: @peterk no, obviously byte/char/short fields take less, if there are several such fields in the object. If your note regards to my suggestion of `byte` size in simple hash map (which I thaught to be implemented without nested array, but with 32 fields), yes, this won't give anything unless keys/values are also shorter than `int`.

Comment: apparently not everything I have read indicates even booleans can take up the space of an "int" because objects keep all the fields aligned and if you only have one byte on an object and all the others are handles or ints the byte will be padded to at least an int.  Some VMs may be smart enough to pack small primitives together if there is more than one.  As far as I know only arrays pack them all in all the time. Of course this would be VM dependent.

Comment: We are talking about the same things in different words.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to optimize really hard and need a full fledged `Map`, you can encapsulate an `Object[]` in an own `AbstractMap` and put there all keys and values interleaved. You need to implement a single method for which you use an `AbstractSet`, but then it gets worse as all the mutating methods throw by default. So you'd have to inspect them all... which may take maybe a whole day.

With Guava-testing you could ensure that your map will really works. Without really profound testing,  I'd recommend to stick with your own tiny interface as `Map` is pretty huge.

Comment: I did this but did not use AbstractMap just implemented all the methods  Abstract map allocates iterators for every operation as well as a Set<Entry> view unless you keep one around, which *does* hit the GC too much, and the iterations add the overhead of hasNext(), next(), getKey(), and getValue() calls for each access. The singly linked list eliminated all of that and was simple.

Comment: @peterk Nice. The `AbstractMap` is good in case when the data just lie around, when you execute any operation very often, you must override it. And you may end up implementing everything. But I don't understand what "overhead of hasNext(), next(), getKey(), and getValue() calls" you mean. There should be none as they all should get inlined. Or are you using Android?

Comment: apparently not a tree or binary map calls compare() and the others call equals() and the hashmap hashCode() in any case the real test for 10,000 random accesses with Integer and String keys it shows there is a difference. Also anything that is an interface makes a virtual call to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I looked at the Java source and yes TreeMap does use a fair amount of memory per node.  So I made two map implementations and tested them.

One a simple singly linked list, the parent with only two fields MyMap { Entry root; int size; } The Entry { key, value, next } The performance turns out for sizes <= 8 was faster than hash map and easy to code and the smaller sizes linearly faster.

I also did the interleaved key/value array with Binary search which performed worse than the simple list as the extra overhead of all the invoking of Comparable.compare() method on the keys ate all the gains and it preformed no faster than HashMap at smaller sizes and got much worse as it got bigger.

So for my case the simplest thing wins.  I simply replace it with a hash map when it gets bigger than 8 and if the HashMap gets below a size of 5 I revert back to the list map.

And you are right for putting. For this application there is probably only one put for several hundred gets and most of the puts just replace the value in the entry and do not trash it.